# Unable to parse some numbers located in innermost pages after using a main link recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how I can parse the order number from such [webpages](https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1/PG7661SCHRANK1/PG0049SCHRANK1/PRO0072) which starts from [here](https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1). To be specific If you go through this [link](https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1), you can see `Read more` link associated with each container which leads to inner pages. You will again see this `Read more` link associated with another set of containers which lead to innermost pages which finally lead to [this page](https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1/PG7661SCHRANK1/PG0049SCHRANK1/PRO0072) where order numbers are.

I can use this piece of code to get the links associated with `read more` links:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://www.rittal.com{}'
url = 'https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1'

def get_links(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    for item_link in soup.select("a.custom-link:contains('Read more')"):
        target_link = base.format(item_link.get("href"))
        yield target_link

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_links(s,url):
            print(item)
```

I can use the following block of code to parse the order numbers:

```
item = soup.select_one("list-filter")
item_ids = re.findall(r"variantId=(.*?)\&",str(item))
if item_ids:
    for item_id in item_ids:
        print(item_id)
```

> What I can't understand is how I can parse the order numbers starting from [this link](https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1) recursively.

Comment: You mean you want to start from [this](https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1) page, get the list of order details for one item, return back and then get to the next item and repeat?

Comment: Yes, that precisely is.

Answer (score 0):

This is some huge scraping, it goes on forever as there are more `Read more` as I traverse through the pages.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('--headless')
   
base = 'https://www.rittal.com{}'
url = 'https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1'

def get_links(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    #This checks if there is any 'Read More' option in the page and if not, it goes to scrape the order details.
    if len(soup.select("a.custom-link:contains('Read more')")) != 0:     
        for item_link in soup.select("a.custom-link:contains('Read more')"):
            target_link = base.format(item_link.get("href"))
            get_links(s,target_link)     #Recursive Call instead of yielding
            # yield target_link
    else:
        get_order_number(link)   

#get's the table in the page containing all the order details
def get_order_number(link):

    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path='path to\chromedriver.exe')
        driver.get(link)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/button[2]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", e)   #cookie prompt removal

        tr_tags = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
        print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text)     #prints the product name before the order details
        for tr in tr_tags:
            print(tr.text)
        driver.quit()
    except:            #when there is no product details/page Eg. Klappe HD
        print('No details available')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
        get_links(s,url)
```

The final product page used Javascript to display the order details and `BeautifulSoup` is not very efficient for dynamic pages. Hence I have used `Selenium` here to scrape the details, you can use other methods that fits you.

I have made `get_links` as the recursive method as you could see in the comments. It works pretty good, since I have used Selenium it might take some time to scrape through all products! Thanks for the good question!

PS : I did not completely see the output at the end as it look some 10 minutes or more(worked super cool and I had to stop it) as there were many products but I have simply answered how to do `recursive call`  and touched a little bit on getting the `order no and other details`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one of the ways you can achieve the same:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://www.rittal.com{}'
url = 'https://www.rittal.com/com-en/products/PG0002SCHRANK1'

def get_links(s,link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    if soup.select_one("list-filter"):
        item = soup.select_one("list-filter")
        ids = re.findall(r"variantId=(.*?)\&",str(item))
        yield ids

    elif soup.select_one("a.custom-link:contains('Read more')"):
        for item_link in soup.select("a.custom-link:contains('Read more')"):
            inner_link = base.format(item_link.get("href"))
            yield from get_links(s,inner_link)

    else:
        yield f"unproductive url: {r.url}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_links(s,url):
            print(item)
```